# Should this person's attitude worry me?

Tags: discussion, behavior

I'm not sure if I should be bringing this up here, but I'm not sure I like a user's behaviour.

The user is rather new here, but after receiving his second downvote, he commented

> There are so many people here who just try to bring you down.... seriously this is my 3rd account here and i don't want to get blocked because of these silly down voters.

So does that mean he, in rage, quit twice before? Or was he just banned because of overall low quality answers?

Comment: I'd suspect the 2nd reason. Kindly advise them to read about correct asking in the help center. There's not much else we can do. Also you shouldn't point out a particular profile, just describing the behavior is enough.

Comment: 3rd account? Pffft.. I gave up flagging [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5113094) at the 6th dupe account. I have not flagged the [7th account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5265828).

Comment: Maybe people lacked feedback on his first 2 accounts, so he doesn't know what he did wrong. Give constructive critism and point out flaws so the person can improve. That's the best thing you can do. SImply pointing to the help section doesn't help if the person already read it.

Comment: @CodeCaster, he will just create more accounts if that one gets banned too.

Comment: He didn't say stupid, he sayed people try to bring you down. It is possible that he didn't get any feedback to what he did wrong. Getting banned by downvotes without feedback can be frustrating, because it doesn't allow for a learning curve. Without a profile we can only speculate. Chances are that if he created 2 more accounts he wants to contribute or doesn't understand the concept in general.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Indeed. Too bad there is no page to ask about feedback ... something like a meta page or so. ;P

Comment: @Tom metapage requires 5 reputation. If he got downvoted from the start it's possible he never had or lost the privilege to ask for feedback, also metapage doesn't have a "feedback" tag so it's confusing for beginners what exactly can be asked on meta.

Comment: Well, this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta isn't hard to find and, well, yes I expect that one is able to do some research. ["How to answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and ["How to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) provide enough information to get either upvotes or to avoid a lot of downvotes. And ["What's reputation"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) tells one how to get these 5 points.

Comment: Other's people attitude should never worry you.

Comment: It seems very likely that they are posting ill-thought out answers, which would be worrying but for it seeming that they seem very likely to be leaving or getting banned regularly, which means the system works. What's to worry about?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I'm with you on this one, even though it may not apply to the specific individual in question here. Getting down-voted with no feedback can leave a poor taste in the mouth of a new user who really wants to help out. I gave up entirely on one SE site for that very reason: downvotes with no feedback, and I was following the rules in its meta.

Comment: @Tom What's http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta doesn't say in any sentence you can use it for feedback abour your questions/answers. It says you can ask "how the site works", request support or give feedback about new ideas. If you already know you can ask for feedback on meta, you will read that into the page, if you don't know already you haven't learned it by reading.

Comment: Well what do you want to do when people just do a "hit&run", aka downvote without leaving any explaination, such 'dupes' are quickly discouraged from joining [so] or continuing on their current account.

Comment: @Gizmo you wonder "why did I get a downvote".  You can either compare your work to others who do *not* get a downvote, or look around for advice on *how to ask* or *how to answer* that is all over the site, or you can decide that everyone is out to get you and get angry.  It is true that many people choose the last response, but people also respond to well-written comments explaining what they did wrong with the same kind of anger.  There are going to be people who get angry when told they did something wrong regardless of what you do.  The solution is to ensure nobody ever posts a bad post.

Answer (score 63):

Should we give a damn what users think?
No, If a post doesn't cross the line into misbehavior we shouldn't care about the poster's underlying attitude.<sup>1</sup>

Every user is allowed to have some attitude, either bad/good, quiet/vibrant, passionate/laid back. What does matter is the quality of the post. That should be the first thing to worry about. After that you might check on the user to make sure the interactions between the user and the community are in the spirit of [the be-nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback).

It really shouldn't matter if this is the first or the tenth account/sock puppet as long as the posts are original work and no interaction between the accounts take place.  Advising the user to not make comments about the down votes is helpful, maybe flag as too chatty. If you have a down-voted  post yourself use it as an example to show that everybody now and then picks up down votes. (You're free to use one of my down voted answers or questions if you don't have one).

There is not much more you can do than helping out with a few edits to show what a quality post should look like or asking in a comment to edit in extra information, maybe find a good example post. If the user doesn't appreciate that and doesn't seem to pick-up all the guidance given, simply move on. Don't get frustrated or get lured into an argument with individuals that assume all their work is done by us.

Sometimes I redirect those users to sites where (community) moderation is less strict or absent. Quora and Yahoo Answers spring to mind.

The rage-quitting (or the speculation of going down that route) is used by such users as a form of power-play. If you give in to such power-play you basically lost and the user did win. The next time you might be giving in more easily and in the end you quit as well. That would be a greater loss to the community and overall quality than just losing users that are not ready yet for the professional and enthusiastic nature of Stack Overflow.

<sup>1. phrases taken from a comment by [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67914/how-can-i-make-clear-a-statement-is-a-hyperbole-or-generalization?noredirect=1#comment130150_67914) and answer from [TRomano](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/67927/14243)</sup>

Comment: Downvotes without comments, though, **do** get frustrating. Been there. While this particular individual might be a jerk because of the extra accounts, how many people who are willing to learn have we driven away with a quick downvote and no comment to help them learn? I disagree entirely, also, about not caring about a user's attitude in general. No users means no worth in the site.

Comment: *"Every user is allowed to have some attitude, either bad/good, quiet/vibrant, passionate/laid back."* ROFL!

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: @JoeSewell you didn't get the message I wanted to convey. And the question is not about down voting without comments. That topic is discussed everyday and my position in that discussion is *we are a popular site for people to ask their question and it's fierce moderation is the reason we are so high ranked on Google. If the moderation needs to change, give up quality as well*

Comment: @JoeSewell Generally speaking, if a user isn't ready to question themselves and the quality of their post on their own initiative, trying to convince them to do so is a losing battle. If a user thinks that downvotes are just  people trying to "bring them down," I would generally expect they aren't prepared for that kind of self examination. You make a good point, though, that we should be careful not to chase away users who *are* ready to improve, but I think those users will usually be more resilient to begin with.

Comment: @jpmc26 It depends whether they are ready to improve or not, take Joe here they are a good example. Threw a fit in another post because they got a down-vote, when I tried to explain why they might have received it they kicked off deleted their question from SO and all their comments from the [related meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306000/692942) *(I assume it was them)* and vowed to never return. You're still here then Joe after all that childish behaviour.

Answer (score 21):

No, this person's attitude shouldn't worry you, it's beyond your control.

Your attitude is within your control. Worry about that.

Comment: So you are Confused? Am I right?

Comment: Good catch there! :D

Comment: @BilalMaqsood I'm not sure, either.

Answer (score 10):

It's a valid sentiment. I do see that somewhat as well. Sometimes I bang out a quick code sample and people start down voting because I forgot a semicolon, or did not close a bracket somewhere.

I used memcpy to answer a C++ question once and was down voted a bunch of times because "memcpy is C, not C++".

Unless the premise of the answer is completely wrong, I usually just add a comment pointing out any improvements that should/could be made. I find this much more productive than down voting, often followed by "no you are wrong" comment which leads to hostile attitude.

And yes, I think we should care, because if people feel treated badly, they won't answer questions and the community will lose whatever expertise those people have.

Comment: That's because `memcpy` is completely inferior to it's C++ counterpart and anyone using it in C++ will gain a large number of nasty surprises when they try to do just about anything useful. You should be downvoted for such answers. In fact, I'm compelled to downvote you again here for it. That has nothing to do with a negative attitude; it's a simple fact that `memcpy` is a massively inferior tool that nobody, ever, should be caught dead using anymore.

Comment: @ventsyv C++ and Linus Torvalds are like news and The Onion. Entertaining, but not to be taken seriously.

Comment: That's an appeal to authority fallacy, and Torvalds isn't even an authority. Try again.

Comment: Indeed, not taking me seriously is a deadly mistake.

Comment: I like this answer since it shows the problem very well. _"Forgot a semicolon"_? Impossible, you are supposed to copy your code, not type it. It is somewhere in the help center or some famous meta post I am sure, but getting from your downvoted question to that post and understanding what went wrong is just about impossible.

Comment: _"memcpy is C not C++"_ does not answer the question. `int` is C too, nothing wrong with it. There is no mention of `std::copy` being implemented via `memcpy` when appropriate, which is a great reason why `std::copy` is superior. You gain safety for free. And the mention that you cannot `memcpy` most objects. SO is a bad platform for side issues like that. In it's own question "Why is memcpy bad in C++?" (for which I can't find a dupe -.-) it may have been upvoted, but as an answer it was correctly downvoted. It takes a while to get that and we should find a way to help with it.

Comment: FWIW I would downvote a C++ answer needlessly using unwrapped `memcpy` as well. And the Linus Torvalds post you linked to is a dumbfounded hate completely irrelevant to the topic at hand (which was, again, whether use of `memcpy` in C++ code was justified, not whether C++ is a good language or not).

Comment: @nwp - copy the code from where? Half the time I don't even have the compiler installed. As for the memcpy - this was years ago and I was not yet familiar with the newly (or newlish at the time) enacted C++ 11 standard. Yet, since the question was concerning POD, the usage I suggested was perfectly fine. Bartek - the Torvalds post was to illustrate that "just because it's old does not mean it's crap" - if you know what you are doing. Using the latest new features just because is there results in poor code more often than not. I deleted the post since it's too distracting.

Answer (score -6):

Worry about answering questions, rather than that guy's **attitude**

Comment: Lol look at you guys talking about down votes without comments...

Comment: I like the humor, so a +1

Comment: I like the humor too, so -1

Comment: If it were a comment on the OP's question, it would have been the most upvoted. Ironical!

Comment: @HappyCoder And it wouldn't have so many downvotes...

Comment: this isn't humor. It's a serious answer.