# Is it acceptable to vote down lazy answers that fix the problem?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

If I see an answer like this:

---

Try this ...

> OP's code copied with some minor fix and no explanation

---

Is it acceptable to vote it down even if it fixes the problem? What is common practice amongst experienced users?

My reasons are two-fold - firstly it's no real use to the next visitor and secondly I see SO as first and foremost a way to educate people who are stuck and the above answer type makes no effort to do so. They may have a copypasta solution, but they don't understand why it works.

Or, should I copy and explain in order to create a better answer?

Comment: Technically, any reason you have to downvote is valid. Users can vote however they want. That said, I usually downvote answers like that, and add a comment asking the user to provide a bit of an explanation.

Comment: Be sure to aim your ire, an answer like that usually starts with a worthless or no-effort question.  Getting rid of helpdesk Q+A needs to get the question closed first.

Comment: I loath "Try this" answers. This usually means "I don't understand the issue. Here's a random change. Try this."

Comment: I would not downvote a working answer unless it is a poor or deprecated answer.  However I might leave a comment requesting more explanation.

Comment: I usually have left a comment asking for more info, unless it's advice to use `!important` to solve a css specificity problem - I still comment event then though!

Comment: Down-vote here :) : I haven't spent much time here.. but from what I can see... the answer should be "as good as" the question and that is it.(<-dot). Not everybody looks for education in here. Not everybody looks for a fast, hacky solution either. A sophisticated question requires a sophisticated answer but a "trivial" question requires a solution. Different types of questions require different answers and if they are "happy" with copy/pasting a random answer they do not understand, that's their problem. If they want more, they should ask?! No need for someone else to do so on their behalf!

Comment: ^---- (s**t) just realized there is no way to down-vote comments :( should I make it an answer? It is definitely not well-thought (beer talking)!

Comment: Downvoting answers which solve problems is just going to lead to even less answers per question. Stop discouraging people from answering questions. There is no benefit in doing that whatsoever. Close bad questions, but do not discourage people from answering. Closing the question will prevent all future answers.

Comment: In my view, advising improvements in comment is more important than downvote, imagine if the users don't know why they receive downvote, they may refuse to contribute the community afterwards, which the impact is greater than leaving lazy answers.

Comment: Down-vote and comment all day long!

Comment: @TravisJ If it discourages bad answers I'm all for it. There is nothing worse then a single line answer with no explanation just a code block, it's damn right lazy and half the time just raises more questions then it answers. The benefit is we discourage poor answers and encourage a higher level of quality to both questions and answers.

Comment: Lol, who voted to close this as "too board"? Seriously??

Comment: @JoeSewell Do you mean [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32570577/692942)? I don't know [tag:clearquest] but I would assume the down-vote is probably because your code doesn't show the problem or what you have attempted to solve the problem. I'd go other [ask] again then spend a bit more time fleshing out your question.

Comment: @urban poor quality answers degrade the site as a whole. People coming here for a "quick fix" do as well.

Comment: Related: [What should a minimal answer contain?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain).

Comment: @JoeSewell Maybe you have like I said I don't know [tag:clearquest] so I'm in no position to advise I was merely pointing out what might reflect the down-vote.

Comment: @CodeCaster Couldn't agree with you more.

Comment: @Joe FWIW that question doesn't look that bad to me.

Comment: @JoeSewell Bit of an over reaction, why not just take a bit of constructive criticism and move on rather then acting like my 6 year old. There is no need to leave over this. Does this happen at work when you are challenged?, do you pack up your things and move on to another job?

Comment: If it's a "typo-fix" answer, then that probably means it's a bad question (Q+A will probably never help anyone else) and down-voting the question is probably more productive.  If I see such a question, I would probably just leave the fix in a comment.

Comment: @TripeHound In which case they shouldn't be trying to answer it in the first place, so they deserve any down-votes they get in my opinion.

Comment: @Lankymart  Agreed.

Answer (score 60):

To quote [the help center's explanation on downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post

So yes, by all means, such answers deserve to be downvoted. Having said that, if you continue reading that page, you'll also see the recommendation:

> If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.

The way I get Stack Exchange is that the answers aren't only there to answer the OP's question, but to evolve into a usable, searchable, reference that can help **others** in the future. While downvoting is definitely appropriate here, it's just half a solution. Unless you comment and explain your downvote, the poster won't necessarily understand what he did wrong, and you're losing out on an opportunity to improve that post.

Comment: Also, if the answer has just been posted, wait a few minutes before downvoting: it may be a (bad) attempt at a FGITW shot, and the user may still be improving it.

Comment: Shog9 (I think it was him) once posted an answer on those foce-commenting FRs pointing out that sometimes *not* commenting when downvoting gets a better response...

Comment: @Deduplicator Shog has all sorts of weird ideas.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - what is FGITW?

Comment: @ToniLeigh short for Fastest Gun In The West. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/223467

Comment: In my view, a poor FGITW is an apt candidate for downvoting. The author should have taken their time. I'm not waiting around for them to post the answer they should have posted in the first place. This behaviour needs stamping out, not pandering to!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Couldn't agree more!

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski: there is no reason to wait with a downvote. If an answer is bad *now*, downvote it *now*. If an answer gets improved later, you still can retract the downvote *then*.

Comment: @Holger to have an option to undo downvote in case if answer is improved within grace period, one would better also add a comment, [to trigger new revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601 "as explained here"). "this answer looks incomplete, why?"

Comment: @gnat: if you suspect that the author plans to do edits within the grace period, or if it indeed looks incomplete, that might be reasonable. In all other cases, I don’t think that reader are required to guess whether this is the author’s intention. It’s *their* problem if they play that game.

Comment: @Holger sorry if I was unclear, my _only_ concern is about making it easier for reader / voter / flagger. Without comment, they can be cheated by author editing their post into shape within grace period, so that their vote can't be reverted and their flag starts looking invalid. With comment, none of this happens, there is an evidence of what was flagged and there is a guaranteed option to revert vote, no matter how fast is the author's edit

Comment: @gnat: well, I never assumed that an author has interest in preventing voters from retracting their downvotes, however, if that happens, both have to live with a sticky downvote then. Flagging is a different issue. I don’t know whether low quality flags still are atomically marked helpful on edits, nevertheless, before asking others via flagging to spent time on a posting, everyone should first ask the author to spent time on fixing attempts. Especially, when the posting/last edit is fresh and the author likely to be still online and reacting.

Comment: @Holger wrt flags, moderators say that [edits automatically dismiss flags as helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252854/165773)

Comment: for me, no need to wait for graceful period, if the answer is appeared with in my graceful period, just skip it, just vote the answer that over graceful period.

Answer (score -12):

No. Either put a comment saying "please add an explanation for the next person that comes searching for this question", or edit the answer yourself.

Sometimes people think the change is self evident and does not need to be explained (missing semicolon, syntax error etc) or simply don't have the time to explain.
Whatever the reason, the answer is still correct and useful.

Comment: Will it help someone else with the same problem (though probably not expressed *exactly* the same way)? Even without doing a thorough exegesis of question, answer and comments? That doesn't seem to be the kind of answer we are talking about here.

Comment: I don't think the self evident answer is at all valid, I don't think people in a position of knowledge should ever assume a level knowledge in someone they're trying to help

Comment: Correct maybe; useful not so much. As I like to plaster all over: Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score -13):

I would say the exception to this is accepted answers. In those cases:

- OP is happy
- Answerer is happy

It is only you who is unhappy in this situation. In this case, instead of
punishing answerer under the [no good deed](http://wiktionary.org/wiki/no_good_deed_goes_unpunished) clause, I say do one of these, in
descending order of "goodness":

- [Suggest] edit answer and upvote
- Add your own answer
- Add comment asking answerer to improve

Comment: just my opinion, voting should not be affected by whether the answer is accepted

Comment: This still constitutes a down-vote in my book, if they improve the answer the down-vote will be removed.

Comment: There is a third party who might not be happy: Person with the same problem who finds the question on google.

Comment: I don't agree - it may be both parties are happy, but that still doesn't make it a _good_ answer. We want _good_ answers for future reference.

Comment: @Lankymart "if they improve the answer the down-vote will be removed" - isn't that a bit optimistic? Or do you just mean when *you personally* downvote something you are conscientious enough to check back and remove the vote if it's improved? Because with no way to notify a downvoter (unless they comment) and no notification of an edit to the downvoted answer, I would have thought an awful lot of downvotes just stick forever, regardless of any improvements. (I'm sure there's a way to get stats on that :-)

Comment: @CupawnTae I certainly try to, I always try to go over my questions / answers where I've left comments on a regular basis.

Comment: @Lankymart I don't doubt it, and I would be the same, but the fact that you even say "where I've left comments" means it's less of an issue in your case - if you have commented, at least the author can then notify you of an update so you can come back and review. If you haven't commented (e.g. someone else has already explained the issue), there will be no notification of updates, and presumably if it takes the author a while to come back to it, it will be less likely that you'll get to see it.